# Cómo puedo agrupar esta consulta de manera que no se repitan los nombres y ruts?

Tags: oracle, sql

Esta es la consulta que llevo, los datos del select corresponden a la tabla datos personal, donde muestra solo información de las personas y la tabla 2 muestra todos los contratos vigentes de los funcionarios donde estos pueden tener muchos contratos, pero solo necesito que se vea un registro por funcionario, mas que nada para ver los datos del funcionario con contrato vigente.

Me gustaría saber cómo debo agrupar esto de manera que solo me muestre 1 registro por funcionario y no de todos los contratos que tiene solo 1.

```
SELECT
    RUT||'-'||DV,
    NOMBRES,
    FONO,
    CORREO_ELECTRONICO
FROM
    TABLA_DATOS_PERSONAL
JOIN TABLA_DATOS_CONTRATOS_VIGENTES ON
    TABLA_DATOS_CONTRATOS_VIGENTES.D_RUT = TABLA_DATOS_PERSONAL.RUT
WHERE
    TABLA_DATOS_CONTRATOS_VIGENTES.D_RUT='VIGENTE'
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta fue simple era solo agregar distinct bajo el select